# Firebug not listing all javascript modules

Tags: javascript, dojo, firebug, amd

I'm having a problem getting Firebug (and Chrome) to list the javascript files/modules that I've defined and included.  I've recently switched from Dojo 1.5 to Dojo 1.9.1 AMD and am including the javascript modules through the require protocol as designed.  This had been working fine until just recently when I changed the Dojo configuration's "async:true"  to  "async:false"  in order to support some legacy code that still needs the "dojo.require" to be recognized and supported.  Changing the Dojo configuration to "async:false" allowed the "dojo.require" calls to work, but somehow broke the ability of Firebug and Chrome to "see" the loaded javascript modules. I just temporarily switched the config back to "async:true" to verify that Firebug successfully listed the javascript modules so it is definitely the cause of the effect.

The functionality of the JSP pages still appear to behave as expected - so the javascript modules are being included as needed, but when I try to view them and set breakpoints in them from Firebug - they are not listed.  If I search for a particular string that appears in one of them, then Firebug will successfully find the javascript code but shows that it is "located" under the heading of something like:

/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js line 328 > Function line 1 > eval (2)

instead of the actual file/module name.  I'm unable to set breakpoints from this view, but if I add a "debugger;" line into the javascript file then Firebug will stop at that location during execution - not an ideal workaround.

Any idea why switching from "async:true" to "async:false" would cause this behavior in Firebug?

Thanks.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've since found a similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627844/javascript-dojo-module-pattern-how-to-debug  but its solution to add Dojo config property  "debugAtAllCosts:true" didn't make a difference for me.

Comment: `debugAtAllCosts` stopped being a thing after 1.6.  Switching `async` from `true` to `false` switches the loader from script injection to sync XHR + eval, which I guess dev tools are having a problem dealing with.  Did it work with 1.5?  (That would have typically used sync XHR + eval too.)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  When I was using 1.5 I didn't have any JavaScript modules so this is new ground for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add has:{'dojo-firebug': true } to your dojoConfig like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dojoConfig = {
        has: {
            'dojo-firebug': true
        }
    };
</script>
```

You can also add it in like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="your_dojo_src_path_here"
        data-dojo-config="has:{'dojo-firebug':true}">
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried your suggestion but it didn't make a difference.   I googled that dojo-firebug property and found that it appears to only be useful for generating a Firebug lite UI for older version of Internet Explorer; if Firebug is already available (as it is in my Firefox) then the property has no effect.  It's better explained here: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/dojo_config/